# Struts 1: How to inject dependencies into Action classes without using a DI container?

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

A client hired us to maintain a really old Struts 1 web application. For a feature request, we need to implement a new Action that depends on a Service class. The original code base consists mainly of spaghetti code and does not use anything like a dependency injection container. We are slowly refactoring everything to follow modern standards, but for now we have to make do with the original code base.

How do I inject the Service into my Action class without introducing a dependency container?

```
package com.example.action;

import com.example.service.ExampleService;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public final class ExampleAction extends Action {
    private ExampleService exampleService;

    // This Action cannot be instantiated by Struts because of its dependency! :(
    public ExampleAction(ExampleService exampleService) {
        this.exampleService = exampleService;
    }

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // ...

        exampleService.doSomething();

        // ...
    }
}
```

I found a lot of information on how to integrate the Spring container with Struts 1, but I could not find anything on how to manipulate Strut's Action instantiation process manually. I really don't want to refactor more than I have to to get the new feature working, so I would prefer a quick and dirty solution where I simply interfere with Strut's Action instantiation process to inject my Service manually.

Comment: Action creation is handled in (IIRC) the request processor, so you *might* be able to do something there, but w/o a unified mechanism to determine what needs to be injected and how it will end up as spaghetti as your current code--you'd be better off integrating an old version of Spring. Unless you have a specific reason to *dynamically* inject services just instantiate it in the action; your unit tests could still inject whatever is needed. But trying to update an S1 app without dealing with the underlying issues is going to create more work than it eliminates.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I actually ended up integrating the oldschool PicoContainer, because it pretty much works out of the box and required only minimal changes.